# K&R exercise 1-9. Putchar and getchar

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

I was doing the exercise 1-9( Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank) of this book and it seems I'm not quite getting it. So far this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == ' ') {
            while (c == ' ') {
                c = getchar();
            }
            putchar(' ');
        } else {
            putchar(c);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

It's wrong since the sentence `hey(blank)(blank)(blank)now` comes as `hey ow`. Always the first letter after de last blank is erased. I think it is a pretty silly bug but I can't see how to fix it. I'll appreciate any piece of advice. 
PS: sorry for my English and if you don't understand something, please tell me.

Comment: first thing to do is indent your code properly. Statements inside the `while`  loop should be indented more than the `while` line, and so on.  This will make it easier to follow the flow of the program in your head.  You shouldn't ever have two consecutive `}` at the same indent level

Comment: `while (c == ' '){
        c = getchar();
    }` : when loop break, need `ungetc(c, stdin)`

Comment: It might help you to take a pen and a paper and to think about what’s happening with `c` and what you print to the output. In your case, the problem is that you ignore the last value of `c` read in the inner while loop.

Comment: Just look at the code.  What happens when the 'while (c == ' ')' fails?

Comment: Well, follow the logic.  What happens when you have a space followed by a non-space?  You skip spaces until you read the non-space character, then you print a space, then you move on to the next loop iteration where you read a new character, discarding the non-space that you read before.  So after printing the space, you need to do something with the next character.  You could use `ungetc` to place it back in the input stream.  That's one way to fix it.

Comment: Don't do any more exercises until you learn how to use gdb or some other debugger.  You are not yet good enough to just type out code, even simple code like this, and get it to work without help, and SO should not be the first thingto turn to for debugging.

Comment: 'I can't see how to fix it' look at the evidence first - the operation fails just when leaving whitespace for the second word.  Look at where that is handled in the code and, sure enough, there is the problem.  If you had single-stepped through with a debugger, you would have spotted the bug, and almost certainly fixed it, by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this if statement (I have formatted it that it could be readable)

```
if (c == ' ')
{
    while (c == ' ')
    {
        c = getchar();
    }
    putchar(' ');
}
```

you are skipping the non-blank character that just has been read because  in the outer loop

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

you are reading the next character.

The program can be written for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int blank = 0;
    int c;

    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF )
    {
        if ( !blank || c != ' '  ) putchar( c );
        blank = c == ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `while (c == ' ')` is reading until it finds a non-space.  So, it stops when you reach the 'n', but you are not putting that character. After the `putchar(' ')`, add a `putchar(c);` to print the character after the string of blanks.

Comment: it should be `if ( c != EOF ) putchar(c);`  in case the file ended after some space

Answer (score 0):

Because in the inner while you are getting the 'n' and then, in the outer while condition, you are getting another character, that is 'o'.